# Can't wake the computer from suspend state with wireless mouse and keyboard

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, usb

I have a Logitech M705 wireless mouse through unifying receiver and a Bluetooth Micorsoft Keyboard. Both work just fine in OS but they won't wake the computer from suspend state. I guess the usb power to the ports is shut off during suspend state.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it up on the BIOS. According to your BIOS you can find some option to tweak that.

If there is not option in your BIOS for that, you can also use `tlp`. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device) question.

Hope it helps.